# Image Upload into Database

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, image-uploading

I try to upload two images for each object of a certain type following those instructions: http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=4642

Thats what my models look like:

#### Models:

```
class Mepager < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :images
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :mepager

     def image_file=(input_data)
         self.filename = input_data.original_filename
         self.content_type = input_data.content_type.chomp
         self.binary_data = input_data.read
     end
end
```

#### Schema:

```
create_table "images", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "content_type"
    t.string   "filename"
    t.binary   "binary_data"
    t.string   "connector"
    t.integer  "mepager_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

#### Controller

```
def new
@mepager = @pimp.build_mepager
@pre_image = @mepager.images.build(:connector => "pre")
@post_image = @mepager.images.build(:connector => "post")
end

def mepager_params
  params.require(:mepager).permit(:id,
    :images_attributes => [:id, :content_type, :filename, :binary_data, :mepager_id, :connector])
end
```

#### Form:

```
<%= simple_form_for :mepager, url: mepager_path, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %> 


<%= f.simple_fields_for :images, @pre_image do |image| %>
    <b>Pre-Image</b>
        <%= image.input :image_file, :as => :file, label: false, input_html:{:size => 15} %>
        <%= image.input :connector %>               
<% end %>

<%= f.simple_fields_for :images, @post_image do |image| %>
    <b>Post-Image</b>
        <%= image.input :image_file, :as => :file, label: false, input_html:{:size => 15} %>
        <%= image.input :connector %>               
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

But if I choose a file in that form and submit it, its not getting saved!

Anyone?

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you instead just save the image link to the database and then upload the image to a given directory on your server, its much better and secure. And for that to work you have to use paperclip look at this example
Start by adding paperclip gem in the gem file like this

```
gem "paperclip", "~> 2.3"
```

After run bundle install in your project directory

Then generate a migration to add the field to your table like this

```
rails g migration add_attach_paperclip
```

Then add these columns to your table

```
class AddattachPaperclip < ActiveRecord::Migration
def self.up
add_column :images, :attach_file_name, :string
add_column :images, :attach_content_type, :string
add_column :images, :attach_file_size, :integer
add_column :images, :attach_updated_at, :datetime
end

def self.down
remove_column :images, :attach_file_name
remove_column :images, :attach_content_type
remove_column :images, :attach_file_size
remove_column :images, :attach_updated_at
end
end
```

The you go and rake you migration

After you change your model for images by adding this

```
has_attached_file :pic
```

After change the name of your file field to `pic`
That is all you need when you want to display your image you just use

```
<%= @image.pic.url %>
```

Comment: But is it possible to attach 2 images to 1 object and map them accordingly? Thats what I meant with the `connector` attribute.

Comment: yes you can what you do just create another migration say add_pic_paperclip then in the model create another validation as attach and then go to your form and add it their as attach

Comment: Sorry, not really getting what you're saying! So you say I have to create a new migration named `add_pic_paperclip`? But what kind of validation do I have to create in my model? And didnt get that with the form either. Could you explain it a little more, that would be awesome.